# show and hide multiple divs on click

Tags: jquery

I have 3 links and each link points to a different version of a document. How can I show/hide them?

Right now, I have a `<div id="defaultTemplate">`. This will be the default. Below it, I have `<div id="Option2" class="hidden">` and `<div id="Option3" class="hidden">`

options 2 and 3 are hidden as they should be, but I want to show/hide each as the user clicks on the links.

Here is my non-working jQuery:

```
$('.option1, .option2, .option3').click(function(){
    var toShow = $(this).attr("class");
    console.log(toShow);
    $('#defaultTemplate').fadeOut(600, function(){
        $('#' + toShow).show();

    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Option2` a **ID** or **class**???

Comment: $('.option1, .option2, .option3') its not class its id $('#option1, #option2, #option3')

Comment: Option2 is a class of the link, as well as an id on the div

Comment: problem is that capital `O` in your ID.. make it small and then try (assuming you have 3 links with class option1, ,2 and 3)

Comment: @pXL - Thanks! My tired eyes looked right past that.

Comment: @pXL add that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: anyone care to justify the downvote and vote to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID's have a capital `O` in `Option2` like this `id="Option2"`

As the classes which you are clicking have small `o` ,

when you do this -

`$('#' + toShow).show();` i.e `$('#option2').show();` , their is no ID with `option2` but their **is** an ID,  `Option2`

You need to change your ID's to `option1`,`option2`,`option3` , with small `o`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `#option1, #option2, #option3` maybe it should help because now you are refering to classes not ids.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for class not for id so try this:

`$('.' + toShow).show();`

Or if you searching for ids than change this line:

`$('#option1, #option2, #option3')`

Answer (score 0):

option1 id is not defined. I think it should be of first div.

```
  $('#Option1, #Option2, #Option3').click(function(){
    var toShow = $(this).attr("class");
    console.log(toShow);
    $('#defaultTemplate').fadeOut(600, function(){
      $('.' + toShow).show();

   });
});
```